# Zend accessing user data in all controllers

Tags: zend-framework, session, action, helper

Searched and searched for some guidance but cant seem to get anything to work.  I wont to access the user data in any index controller to save repetetive code.  I have created a ACTION HELPER which calls the Session and returns the users data.  Below is how I implemented it all.  Calling the helper works but I cant get the data out in any controller.

Application.ini

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZC"

Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initActionHelpers()
{
Zend_controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new ZC_Action_Helpers_User());   
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

    Class ZC_Action_Helpers_User extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
    {       
    public function direct()
        {
            $storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
            $data = $storage->read();
            $this->_user = $data;        
        }    
    }
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->_helper->user;

    }
```

I have no problems with the code but say for example how would I get the USERNAME or USERID from the helper???

Thanks for taking the time in looking at this.

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your plugin function have to return the user information and not set it as a class variable:

```
Class ZC_Action_Helpers_User extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{       
public function direct()
    {
        $storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
        $data = $storage->read();
        return $data;        
    }    
}
```

Then you can use the plugin in any controller you need:

```
$user  = $this->_helper->User->Direct()
```

You might want to rename some of these functions and classes.

Comment: HI I implelemted the above in my IndexConrtoller but when I print_r($user) it does nothing the data doesnt seem to be outputting?

Comment: Sorry Aporat did returh $data !!!! Thanks once again, so when I do $this->_user = $data it sets as class varible which means what?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declared in bootstrap path to helpers...

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers');
```

Next use google for this simply question.... [howto use helper in ZF](http://Using%20Action%20Helpers%20in%20Zend%20Framework%20-%20Rob%20Allen%27s%20DevNotes)

Comment: Hi derhaa, the helper path is added in the application.ini

Comment: autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZC"  this will detect the path of the helpers.